# Jquery/CSS "Fan Out" Animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Been trying to figure this one out but am stumped!

I want to create an animation with Jquery/CSS where a stack of images rotate and create an arc. I'm thinking the easiest way to do this is to stack them and then rotate them from the center as illustrated below.

[image]

I'd like all four images (only four since the first one remains where it is) to rotate at the same time and speed but stop at 45, 90, 135 and 180 degrees.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need jQuery for this, as using css animations you can set a rotation for things. Simply create the shape/image you'd like, then set a rotation for it.

```
.spin {
    animation: spin 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you need multiple lines to fadeIn/out, you can replace the from/to in the CSS with multiple percent breakpoints to have it change at different points during the animation's lifecycle. Check out these example animations I found, seems to have what you're looking for.
https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

Comment: Thanks Jared. That's not quite what I was looking for. I figured something out which I'll add below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out that works exactly the way I want. I just thought there may be a way to do it with less code.

CSS:

```
.img-div  {
position:absolute;
transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
.deg45 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.deg90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.deg135 {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.deg180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

JS (on a button click or page load, etc...)

```
$('.img2').addClass('deg45');
$('.img3').addClass('deg90');  
$('.img4').addClass('deg135');
$('.img5').addClass('deg180');
```

HTML

```
<div class="img-div img1"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8qlE.png" /></div>
<div class="img-div img2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8qlE.png" /></div>
<div class="img-div img3"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8qlE.png" /></div>
<div class="img-div img4"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8qlE.png" /></div>
<div class="img-div img5"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8qlE.png" /></div>
```